# Mailchimp like email templates for individual email / transactional email

Tags: html-email, mailchimp, mandrill, email-templates, mailchimp-api-v3.0

Please, see the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8t2Q.png) (of an email) that I received for my transaction.

I would like to create the similar email template for the users who interact on my site.

I really like `mailchimp` and it is email templates.  But I cannot send a transactional email, triggered by the recipient's action like purchase confirmations etc.  I came to know about `mandrill`, but I could not sign up for `mandrill`.

I want to know how these email templates (refer above screenshot) are created... is there any free website that I can use?

Answer (score 1):

There is also something called [Mautic](https://www.mautic.org/). This is an open source marketing automation tool. Which has lots of possibilities and where you can also use your own email templates.

Hope this helps in a way!